# Запрет смены картинок по нажатию кнопок lightbox2

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, lightbox

Использую lightbox2 галерею и столкнулся с такой проблемой: если кликнуть на картинку и потом нажать на клавиатуре стрелку вперёд или назад, то галерея начинает сменять картинки.

Как отключить эту функцию?

```
<a class="example-image-link" href="<?=$singlePic;?>" data-lightbox="singlePicture">
    <img class="example-image" src="<?=$arItem['PICTURE']?>" alt="image-1">
</a>

lightbox.option({
  alwaysShowNavOnTouchDevices: false,
  wrapAround:false,
  alwaysShowNav:false,
  showImageNumberLabel:false,
  disableScrolling:false
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы отменит навигацию с клавиатуры, нужно удалить строку `this.enableKeyboardNav();` из прототипа `Lightbox.prototype.showImage = function() {};`. На выходе у вас должно остаться следующее:

```
Lightbox.prototype.showImage = function() {
  this.$lightbox.find('.lb-loader').stop(true).hide();
  this.$lightbox.find('.lb-image').fadeIn(this.options.imageFadeDuration);

  this.updateNav();
  this.updateDetails();
  this.preloadNeighboringImages();
};
```